# Docker build leads to "no space left on device" on Windows 10

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I´m facing a weird problem when I want to build my image on Windows. I haven´t used **Docker** for anything else, so the installation can be considered as fresh. There are no volumes at all and no images yet.

When I´m trying to build my application from my Dockerfile, it finishes with this error

```
docker build ./
Sending build context to Docker daemon   1.4 GB
Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /.bowerrc: no space left on device
```

I´ve read that you can increase the basesize of docker, but I haven´t found a solution for that for Windows (Why is this even limited by default?)

`docker info` prints some stuff, but it doesn´t show anything about the basesize under "Storage Driver" at all

```
$ docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: tmpfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: aa8187dbd3b7ad67d8e5e3a15115d3eef43a7ed1
runc version: 9df8b306d01f59d3a8029be411de015b7304dd8f
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.8-moby
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.5
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.934 GiB
Name: moby
ID: GUXQ:KPKS:PHBV:BMEF:QHHM:B2YG:MWPB:2W5H:Z3GX:27YS:QBT6:O4RV
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 13
 Goroutines: 21
 System Time: 2017-02-19T20:15:57.8764828Z
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

According to some posts in the internet, this was once or is the way to go on Linux, but it doesn´t work on Windows

> **docker daemon --storage-opt dm.basesize=20G**

What is wrong with my docker installation and how can I increase the basesize?

Comment: Are you sure you need to send all 1.4GB to the daemon?  This [comment](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23470#issuecomment-248332511) on the docker issues page may be of assistance if you need too.

Comment: I don't know as it is my first attempt to build an image. It contains several applications and I don't know yet if it is the right way to put everything in one image. Thank you, will look into it

Comment: I don't know exactly how large the applications are, but using [dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/dockerignore-file) or [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) might help.

Comment: Don't put any files in the folder where docker files is. Everything is in that folder will be sent to docker to build. So make sure your docker file is in the folder and only relevant files.

Comment: if now tested it with a plain ubuntu image "docker run ubuntu:17.04" - same issue

Comment: Can you accept the answer? It solves the problem that is in the question. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem on Windows. One of this two settings should solve this problem:

- Increase Memory that Docker is using. If is it 2GB, add more
- Increase "Disk image max size" - initially is 60, move it to 80 GB

This should be enough, but depends on complexity of what you are building. In some cases increase of Swap would be needed. The initial Swap of Docker is 1024 MB

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I reset to factory default , then select : delete all image.
At advanced tab : increase 'Disk image max size' (I modify to 80 GB)
Then build docker again

Answer (score 0):

I´ve reinstalled Docker and now it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't have been the underlying issue for the OP back in 2017, but if you're experiencing this problem with Windows 10 1903, then you may be running into Docker for Windows [issue #4100](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4100) ("Windows 1903 fails when storage-opt used").

On January 6th, 2020, a [commit](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/commit/26dc16fe2b5f69d37486ffb0ecf565280fa6ca9a) was pushed to the [docker-ce GitHub repository](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce) that, from the comments (below), appears to implement a workaround to the underlying bug in Windows.

> - microsoft/hcsshim#718 wclayer: Work around Windows bug when expanding sandbox size
>
>   - fixes microsoft/hcsshim#708 Windows Host Compute Service bug breaks docker (and other) sandboxes bigger than 20G on Windows 1903
>   - fixes microsoft/hcsshim#624The hcsshim on Windows 10 1903 always fails to build Docker image
>   - fixes/addresses docker/for-win#3884 An error occurred while attempting to build Docker image (especially this comment and the next comments after: docker/for-win#3884 (comment))
>   - fixes/addresses docker/for-win#4100 Windows 1903 fails when storage-opt used
>   - fixes moby/moby#36831 hcsshim::PrepareLayer failed in Win32: The parameter is incorrect (moby/moby#36831 (comment))
>   - fixes Stannieman/audacity-with-asio-builder#5 Docker won't build container
>   - fixes MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs#3523 Error when running build with storage-opts set
>   - fixes moby/moby#39524 Docker build windows 19.03 --storage-opt size>20G

Unfortunately, no new release of Docker has yet been made that includes this commit, so those of us on 1903 and experiencing this bug are kind of stuck for the time being.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're doing this with a dev environment, just run:

```
docker system prune -a -f
```

**Caution:** Do not run this on a production environment

Comment: That's a destructive command; while it is useful, you shouldn't "just run it" without understanding what it does.

Comment: Though you are correct that this is a destructive command, the OP says he was having a problem when building his image. Assuming it was a dev environment, this is the easiest way to do it. Any other containers can be recreated anyway on a dev environment. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Note for future readers: beware this command deletes all of your images, in use or not.